# How to add custom encryption in Netty 4?

Tags: netty

I have an application built with Netty 4, and need to add a custom encryption implementation.
What is the recommended way to do it?

Using the echo application as example (https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/echo) I want to add an independent handler in the pipeline to encrypt/decrypt the content.

Comment: Could you please add more details to your question like sample code, encrypting what in you app etc. Otherwise this question would be downvoted and closed

Answer (score 0):

You would just implement your own `ChannelOutboundHandler` for the encryption part and your own `ChannelInboundHandler` for the decryption part. Then add it to the `ChannelPipeline`. That said I would argue that rolling your own encryption is usually not a good idea and 99% of the times it is preferred to re-use something that already exists.

Comment: I am rewriting the server side of a C application, that uses a legacy protocol, with more that 20 thousand clients, so I am re-using something that exists!

Answer (score 0):

Following Norman Maurer suggestion I wrote this pipeline:

```
public class MyServerInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

  @Override
  public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
    ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();

    pipeline.addLast(new LengthFrameDecoder());
    pipeline.addLast(new CryptoDecoder());
    pipeline.addLast(new HeaderDecoder());
    pipeline.addLast(new StringDecoder());

    pipeline.addLast(new LengthPrepender());
    pipeline.addLast(new CryptoEncoder());
    pipeline.addLast(new HeaderEncoder());
    pipeline.addLast(new StringEncoder());

    pipeline.addLast(new MyServerHandler());
  }
}

public class CryptoDecoder extends ByteToMessageDecoder {

    @Override
    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in, List<Object> out) throws Exception {
        out.add(decrypt(in));
    }

    private ByteBuf decrypt(ByteBuf data) {
        return CryptoUtil.decrypt(data);
    }

}
```